# How to check database with php variables like this?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to check database with php variables like this ?

I have

```
$check = "1234567890";
```

This is table : check_data

```
 _________ ______________________________________________________________
|   id    |                         key_pass                             |
|_________|______________________________________________________________|
|____1____|_______________1234567890abcdefghij___________________________|
|____2____|_______________6545ryu76543werfdt54___________________________|
|____3____|_______________345jfuryt75yrhtufkgo___________________________|
|____4____|_______________weoiufoiweu9ew8ew8w8___________________________|
|____5____|_______________oi34ioruiofuefiusdfo___________________________|
|____6____|_______________iuyiuysdifuysfiuyfds___________________________|
```

i want to check like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM check_data WHERE key_pass(first char to ten char) = '$check'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if($result)
  {echo "found";}
else
  {echo "not found";}
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: Note that PHP's mysql_ API is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

Check MySQL manual, you're looking for `SUBSTRING` function.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM check_data WHERE SUBSTRING(key_pass, 1, 10) = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($check) . "';
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with **[`LEFT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left)**

```
LEFT(key_pass , 10);
```

Like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM check_data WHERE LEFT(key_pass , 10) = '$check'";
```

Also you can use **[`SUBSTRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)** like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM check_data WHERE SUBSTRING(key_pass ,1, 10) = '$check'";
```

Comment: Substring starts from 1. Source: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php

Answer (score 2):

the function you need is LIKE,

```
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM check_data WHERE key_pass like ('$check%')";
```

you could also do

```
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM check_data WHERE SUBSTR(key_pass,1,10) = '$check%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `LEFT()` function like this:

```
ql = "SELECT * FROM check_data WHERE left(key_pass,10) = '$check'";
```

There are a whole family of string functions that can be useful. Check the MySQL [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM check_data WHERE SUBSTRING(key_pass, 1, 10)= '$check'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM check_data WHERE key_pass LIKE  % $check %";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if($result)
  {echo "found";}
else
  {echo "not found";}
```

Comment: Change `% $check %";` to `$check %";`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    "SELECT * FROM check_data WHERE SUBSTR(key_pass,1,10) = ".$check
```

or

```
    "SELECT * FROM check_data WHERE key_pass LIKE '".$check."%'"
```